# How to include navigation properties recursively

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, navigation-properties, entity-framework-5

I have 2 databases, each with a corresponding EntityFramework DB Context and I am using Entity Framework 5, Code-First.

I have tables resembling the following:

```
Table     : Foo (resides in database 1)
-- Column : Id (is primary key)
-- Column : ParentId (is foreign key into Foo)
-- Column : BarId (is foreign key into Bar)

Table     : FooBar (resides in database 1)
-- Column : Id (is primary key)
-- Column : FooId (is foreign key into Foo)
-- Column : BarId

Table     : Bar (resides in database 2)
-- Column : Id (primary key)
```

Then, I have entities `Foo`, `FooBar` in `Database1DbContext` and `Bar` in `Database2DbContext`.

`Foo` has navigation properties `Parent` (of type `Foo`), `Children` (of type `ICollection<Foo>`) and `Bar` (of type `Bar`).
`FooBar` has navigation properties `Foo` (of type `Foo`) and `Bar` (of type `Bar`).

Now, what I want is to be able to `.Include(foo => foo.Bar)`, such that `Bar` is loaded up for all the `Parent` and `Children` of a `Foo` as well.

I hope I have not been too confusing.

PS: I know there is going to be an issue setting up the `Bar` navigation property since it is on a different database. I saw suggestions in some related answers suggesting either views or synonyms. Any answers that also take into account that aspect of my situation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You cannot make cross context queries or cross context eager / lazy loading. You must load Bar instances yourselves for all required Foo and FooBars.

Comment: Fair enough, but how would I do it if the added complication of different databases wasn't there? That is really my question.

Comment: EF doesn't have support for hierarchical queries so you would need one additional column (something like `TreeId`) to load whole single hierarchy with all its nested nodes by normal query where you can use `Include`.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies things a lot.